# Autologout gnome wayland

Tags: linux, video, hybrid-graphics

Manjaro, gnome. If I try to log in with "Gnome" I immediately return back to gdm login screen. I can log in and work with "Gnome Xorg". For quite a while wayland seemed to be working OK; this problem started about a month and a half ago.

Would it be possible that something is incompatible in some `dot directory` and I could rename it and log in? If so - which directory/directories would be good candidates for renaming?

Alternatively - the system is Thinkpad P70 with Intel and NVIDIA Quadro M4000M graphics. I am not quite sure which driver would be best to use, but is there a point even trying to make it work with wayland?

```
> inxi -G                                                                                                                                                                       
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel HD Graphics P530 driver: i915 v: kernel
  Device-2: NVIDIA GM204GLM [Quadro M4000M] driver: nvidia v: 545.29.06
  Device-3: Chicony Integrated Camera driver: uvcvideo type: USB
  Display: x11 server: X.org v: 1.21.1.9 with: Xwayland v: 23.2.2 driver: X:
    loaded: modesetting dri: iris gpu: i915 resolution: 3840x2160~60Hz
  API: EGL v: 1.5 drivers: iris,nvidia,swrast
    platforms: gbm,x11,surfaceless,device
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6.0 compat-v: 4.5 vendor: intel mesa v: 23.1.9-manjaro1.1
    renderer: Mesa Intel HD Graphics P530 (SKL GT2)
```